# how to update model after droping coulmn from sql database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller, model

I droped catalog_filename coulmn from database and I see this error :

Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
The relationship 'J_DBModel.FK__CATALOG_T__CATEG__41B8C09B' was not loaded because the type 'J_DBModel.CATALOG_TBL' is not available.
The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:
The required property 'CATALOG_FILENAME' does not exist on the type 'Javad_New.Models.CATALOG_TBL'.

In my model catalog_filename is still existed .

```
    public long CATALOG_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> CATEGORY_FK { get; set; }
    public string CATALOG_TITLE { get; set; }
    public string CATALOG_DESC { get; set; }
    public string CATALOG_CATEGORY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CATALOG_PAGENO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> CATALOG_RTL_FLAG { get; set; }
    public string CATALOG_FILENAME { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CATALOG_DATE { get; set; }

    public virtual CATEGORY_TBL CATEGORY_TBL { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Make changes to the database
```

The first step is to make the necessary changes to your database. In this example, the only change being made is to a column name. Simple enough. It is important to note that if you have any stored procedures, etc, that rely on that column name, those should be updated as well.

2. Open the .edmx file

The model exists in your project as an .edmx file. Open the Solution Explorer (ctrl + alt + L) and type .edmx into the search bar at the top. Your model should appear (it’s the only one with that extension). Open it up and you will see a diagram of connected tables.

3. Delete the old table from the model

Before updating the model, it is necessary to delete the existing version of the table(s) you changed from the model. In the .edmx, right-click in the area between tables and select Model Browser. It will open a file tree of all the tables contained in your model. Delete every instance of the table you changed in your database. I find it helpful to enter the name of the modified table in the search bar at the top of the model browser, which will show you all tables in the model with that name. Delete them! Note that attempting to Update Model from Database without deleting the old tables first will not truly update the model, and your app may not compile correctly.

4. Update Model from Database

Now that your old table is deleted, right-click in the .edmx and select Update Model From Database. You will see the following screen:

Answer (score 0):

In code first pattern never (delete / change) in sql.
you should manage things from migration
in your case, just add column to table from sql then delete from c# class and add new migration